# Can I do for with index in F#

Tags: f#

in Nemerle I can do it like this : `foreach (v in lst with index)`

is there something alike on F# ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, with higher-order functions there is [Seq.iteri](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370541.aspx) and [Seq.mapi](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee340431.aspx), with counter-parts in some of the other collection modules like `Array` and `List`.